# Invalid element type

Tags: reactjs, cjsx

```
// This is my test.cjsx
React = require 'react'
createClass = require 'create-react-class'
DataGrid = require './grid/react/TestJs'

module.exports = createClass
    getInitialState: ->
        fullName: ''   
    render: ->
        <div className='greeting'>
           <input type='button'/>
           <DataGrid/>
        </div>

// This is my TestJs.js file
const React = require('react');

class DefaultRow extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
              Hello!
            </div>
        )
    }
};

export default DefaultRow;
```

> > I got this error always - "Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object." I double check the export default but I think it is fine.

Comment: I tried with module.exports and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to mount your root component in some DOM element.
Use react-dom for this case. 
For example:

```
import { render } from 'react-dom'

render(
<App></App>
,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

Comment: I do have it - 
ReactDOM.render routes, document.querySelector('.contents')    in main.cjsx file. 

And I have routes.cjsx as:  

React = require 'react'
{BrowserRouter, Route} = require 'react-router-dom'
Hello = require './TestJs'

module.exports = <BrowserRouter>
        <Route exact path="/home" component={Hello}/>
    </BrowserRouter>

Comment: @rneupane Try this: DataGrid = require ('./grid/react/TestJs').default